# How to console.log big number with normal notation but not scientific notation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJn6D.png)

like the picture shows, when console.log huge number in javescript, it will output a number with scientific notation, but I want it shows with normal notation, what should i do?

Comment: `BigInt(<number>).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

When you console log, just use precision and print it.

Code Example:

```
var num = 990000000000000000000000
num.toPrecision(25)
```

Result:

```
"990000000000000020971520.0"
```

Comment: And how do they know what param to pass to toPrecision?